# MongoDB query to get CPU usage

Tags: mongodb

Using mongodb, I know that I can use the command

```
db.serverStatus()
```

Which will return a lot of information about the current mongo instance, including memory information:

```
"mem" : {
    "bits" : 64,
    "resident" : 4303,
    "virtual" : 7390,
    ...
}
```

Is there anything similar, or anything in this output that I may be missing, that will also report **CPU** usage details?

i.e.

```
"cpu" : {
    "usr" : 32,
    "wa"  : 16,
    "id"  : 52
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `top` command and check if the output gives you necessary information. Switch to admin database and  issue:

```
 db.runCommand( { top: 1 } )
{
        "totals" : {
                "note" : "all times in microseconds",
                "Orders.orders" : {
                        "total" : {
                                "time" : 107211,
                                "count" : 56406
                        },
                        "readLock" : {
                                "time" : 107205,
                                "count" : 56405
                        },
                        "writeLock" : {
                                "time" : 6,
                                "count" : 1
                        },
                        "queries" : {
                                "time" : 105,
                                "count" : 1
                        },
                        "getmore" : {
                                "time" : 0,
                                "count" : 0
                        },
                        "insert" : {
                                "time" : 0,
                                "count" : 0
                        },
                        "update" : {
                                "time" : 0,
                                "count" : 0
                        },
                        "remove" : {
                                "time" : 0,
                                "count" : 0
                        },
                        "commands" : {
                                "time" : 0,
                                "count" : 0
                        }
                },.... rest clipped as it gives per db stats
```

Comment: This is incorrect as it does not return host CPU usage metrics.