# Is it possible to know how much time MongoDB has spent for parsing a query?

Tags: c#, mongodb, parsing, profiling

I have a query which filter a field against a large (> 100K) number of values using the `$in` operator. It is quite slow. There is an index on the field (IXSCAN is reported by profiler).

I was wondering if there was any way to see how much time MongoDB take to parse 
the query (which is sent as BSON if i am not mistaken).

I think C# (since i'm using C# driver) is also taking some time to generate the BSON data but it cannot be reported by MongoDB since it's happening client side.

---

EDIT: here is the query plan:

```
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "Foo.Bar",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "ExternalKeys" : {
                                "$in" : [
                                        {
                                                "A" : 0,
                                                "B" : 0,
                                                "C" : 34228
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "A" : 0,
                                                "B" : 1,
                                                "C" : 540830
                                        },
                                        ... (many like that)

                                        {
                                                "A" : 5,
                                                "B" : 3,
                                                "C" : 773660
                                        }
                                ]
                        }
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                        "ExternalKeys" : 1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "ExternalKeys_1",
                                "isMultiKey" : true,
                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                        "ExternalKeys" : [
                                                "ExternalKeys"
                                        ]
                                },
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : false,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "ExternalKeys" : [
                                                "[{ A: 0.0, B: 0.0, C: 34228.0 }, { A: 0.0, B: 0.0, C: 34228.0 }]",
                                                "[{ A: 0.0, B: 1.0, C: 540830.0 }, { A: 0.0, B: 1.0, C: 540830.0 }]",
                                                ... (many like that)
                                                "[{ A: 5.0, B: 3.0, C: 773660.0 }, { A: 5.0, B: 3.0, C: 773660.0 }]"
                                        ]
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "....",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "3.4.10",
                "gitVersion" : "078f28920cb24de0dd479b5ea6c66c644f6326e9"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: I've asked something similar to this in the past, maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39048602/1790644) can help?

Comment: It could be many things. How big (RAM etc.) is the server where your MongoDB instance is installed and how big are your indexes? Also you can add .explain() to your query and see exactly how Index was used. You can add the result here.

Comment: @AlexP. : i have added explain() info but I don't think it will help.

Comment: It actually does help a lot. Cause you can see that the `"indexBounds"` is working properly. There are many examples out there, where although it was using the IXSCAN the indexBounds were looking wrong in combination with the query. In your case it does look good though. But as you wrote in your second edit, it doesn't have to do with mongodb. It's rather your C# MongoDB driver. That's why I said it could be many things